# django-filter compose filtered url

Tags: django, url, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and I would like to link to the view with a pre-set filter.

At this time, I'm doing like this:

```
<a href='{{ url "order_list" }}/?year=2023'>
```

or

```py
urlnext = (
    reverse('order_list') +
    "?year=2023"
)
return HttpResponseRedirect(urlnext)
```

I would like to know if exists a more elegant approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `?year=2023` is not a good idea. For `2023` this is indeed not a problem. But imagine that the *value* itself contains a question mark or ampersand, then that would generate a query like `?keyword=foo&bar&key=bar`, so it would "cut off" the `&bar`.

You can work with a `QueryDict` for this, which is basically what `request.GET` and `request.POST` are:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd['year'] = 2023

return HttpResponseRedirect(f'{reverse('order_list')}?{qd.urlencode()}')
```

If the value (or key) for example contains an ampersand or question mark, it will [*percent-encode* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) these:

```
>>> qd.urlencode()
'keyword=foo%26bar%3F'
```

Comment: QueryDict is the way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternative ways to achieve the same result using Django's `urlencode` function to construct the query parameters.

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

filter_values = {'year': '2023'}  

url = f"{reverse('order_list')}?{urlencode(filter_values)}"

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```